# upper limit DO Fortran

Tags: fortran

I am new in Fortran and i have this problem.

When i ran this DO is ok:

```
integer, parameter :: Int10Type = selected_int_kind (10)
INTEGER (Int10Type), PARAMETER :: TOTAL_TIME = 1000, TOTAL_INI = 200
INTEGER (Int10Type):: t, z
REAL (16), DIMENSION(TOTAL_Z, TOTAL_TIME) :: current
DO t = 1, TOTAL_TIME
   current(TOTAL_Z, t) = TEMP_INI
END DO
DO t = 1, TOTAL_TIME - 1
  DO z = 2, (TOTAL_Z - 1)
    current(z, t + 1) = current (z, t) + KAPPA*DELTA_T*((current(z - 1, t) -2.0*current(z, t) + current(z + 1, t)) / DELTA_Z**2)
  END DO
END DO
```

But, when i increment var limite

```
    integer, parameter :: Int10Type = selected_int_kind (10)
INTEGER (Int10Type), PARAMETER :: TOTAL_TIME = 1000000000, TOTAL_INI = 200
INTEGER (Int10Type):: t, z
REAL (16), DIMENSION(TOTAL_Z, TOTAL_TIME) :: current
DO t = 1, TOTAL_TIME
   current(TOTAL_Z, t) = TEMP_INI
END DO
DO t = 1, TOTAL_TIME - 1
  DO z = 2, (TOTAL_Z - 1)
    current(z, t + 1) = current (z, t) + KAPPA*DELTA_T*((current(z - 1, t) -2.0*current(z, t) + current(z + 1, t)) / DELTA_Z**2)
  END DO
END DO
```

The output of the program is 'killed'
Why? what i do bad?

Comment: I'm curious, in which capacity you're learning FORTRAN? Academic, pure curiosity, or job related?

Comment: it's academic. i'm student of physical in Argentina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`integer(10)` means `integer(kind=10)`, not an integer with at least 10 decimal digits.  It is up to a compiler what kind=10 means. There is no guarantee that kind=10 even exists!   If you want to specify 10 decimal digits you should use:

```
integer, parameter :: Int10Type = selected_int_kind (10)
integer (kind=Int10Type) :: i
```

Then write your program as:

```
integer, parameter :: Int10Type = selected_int_kind (10)

INTEGER (Int10Type), PARAMETER :: limite = 1000000000_Int10Type, lim = 200
INTEGER (Int10Type):: i, j
DO i = 1, limite
  DO j = 1, lim
     !I work with a matrix
  END DO
END DO
```

Notice that the type has also been specified on the large constant value.

Alternatively, if your compiler provides the ISO Fortran Environment feature of Fortran 2003, you can request an 8 byte (64 bit) integer in a portable way:

```
use iso_fortran_env

INTEGER (INT64), PARAMETER :: limite = 1000000000_INT64, lim = 200
INTEGER (INT64):: i, j
DO i = 1, limite
  DO j = 1, lim
     !I work with a matrix
  END DO
END DO
```

P.S.  1000000000 should fit into a 4-byte (signed) integer since 2**31 = 2,147,483,648, so the default integer of most Fortran compilers should work.   You can probably just use `integer` without specifying a kind!   With `iso_fortran_env`, `INT32` should suffice.   If this doesn't solve your problem, perhaps your array is too big ... you may need to show us more code.

P.P.S.  In response to the additional source code.  The `t` do loop goes from 1 to `total_time`, but you use the 2nd index as `t+1`, which means that the largest value will be `total_time+1`.  This exceeds the 2nd dimension of `current`.  You have an array subscripting error.  If you compile with subscript bounds checking the compiler will find this for you. With gfortran, either use -fcheck=all or -fbounds-check.

Comment: Your iso_fortran_env needs to have a F2008 flavour for the bitwise kind parameters.

Comment: I try this but don't work. I put all my program. i us a very big array, and is possible to the error is here. I us this compiler: GNU Fortran (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: i forget the -1 in do limtis, but this isn't the error. It's possible to the problem is in the dimension of marix? thanks

Comment: This large array might exceed the stack size of your process.  You may need to either increase the stack size or make the array allocatable and allocate it.  That will typically place it on the heap instead of on the stack.  There are Fortran stackoverflow questions on this topic.

Comment: Here is how to try the allocation approach: `real, dimension (:,:), allocatable :: current`.  Then in the active code: `allocate ( current (TOTAL_Z, TOTAL_TIME) )`

Comment: I us allocatable and it's work. Thanks many much. My problem now is, this matrix needs a lots of memory  (Dim = 20 * 1E+8) and have this error: Operating system error: Cannot allocate memory
Allocation would exceed memory limit. But i thinks this matriz isn't very big. The solution is cut the matrix in 2?

Comment: If you are asking for 20E+8 8 byte items, that is 16 Gbytes.   That is a big matrix and a lot of memory.   It depends on the computer that you are running it on whether this is possible.  Decreasing the size of the matrix may be the best solution.

Comment: yes, i do the count and is much memory what is need. Thanks very much.